# Bootstrap 4+ - Vertically+horizontal align 2 divs on top of each other inside another div with height set

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am simply trying to create a div that has a background image and in the middle of this div i have 2 other divs that I like them to be vertically and horizontally centered inside the first div, but I want them to be on top of each other. I have tried every possible way to get this to work, they never directly on top of each other.

```
<div style="height:400px;background-color:red;margin-top:auto;margin-bottom:auto">
    <div class="d-flex  justify-content-center h-100">
        <div style="width:200px"> div 1</div>
        <div style="width:200px"> div 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should they be siblings (<div></div> <div></div>) or can be parent-child (<div> <div></div> </div>)?

Comment: They should be siblings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the classes "flex-column" and "align-items-center" to the container, and ;  and "margin:0 auto" to the inner divs, in order to center them:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
    <div style="width:200px; margin:0 auto; background: pink"> div 1</div>
    <div style="width:200px; margin:0 auto; background: lightblue"> div 2</div>
</div>
```